# Having problems sending data to statsd / graphite database on docker from outside container

Tags: docker, graphite, statsd

I'm having issues getting data sent into a statsd container.  I can successfully send data while on the command line inside the container itself.  I need to be able to send statistic data to it from the host machine or from another Docker container.

I'm using Kitematic, I can see that the selection for 'bridge' network is checked on both containers.  Using a bridge network was a suggestion I found for this issue.

I also tried passing '-P' to Docker while running the command to build the container, as that was supposed to expose the ports.  I didn't notice a difference in the way it behaved when sending data from the other container.

Example of code that runs to create fake statistics using port 8125 on localhost (taken from this Docker container webpage https://hub.docker.com/r/graphiteapp/graphite-statsd)

> Let's fake some stats with a random counter to prove things are working.

```
while true; do echo -n "example:$((RANDOM % 100))|c" | nc -w 1 -u     127.0.0.1 8125; done
```

The container is created using the following command:

```
docker run -d --name graphite --restart=always -p 80:80 -p 2003-2004:2003-2004 -p 2023-2024:2023-2024 -p 8125:8125/udp -p 8126:8126 graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
```

I've tried making sure both are on the same 'bridge' network.  I'm running Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Enterprise.  I've found several commands dealing with iptables and networking on Linux, but I feel like I'm missing something.    I might also mention that statsd uses UDP connection on port 8125 by default.

If I try running the example command from another container on the bridge network, I don't get any result.  I know the data (from another container) is not getting over correctly because I can't see it in the metrics that get received on the statsd dashboard.

I can `ping localhost:8125` and get a response from within another container.  From the outside (Powershell window on the host machine) it won't resolve.

```
 PING localhost:8125 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
 ^C
 --- localhost:8125 ping statistics ---
 3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
 round-trip min/avg/max = 0.024/0.035/0.052 ms>
```

If I run `docker container ls` then I get the following:

[image: updated container ls screenshot]

Comment: Although it appears to be working, you can't ping ports. All you're doing is pinging your Windows host.

Comment: Your description of what you've done is correct. Running the container on `:8125` (and `:8126`) using `--publish` is correct and the service should be exposed on your host's `:8125` (etc.) port(s). What do you get from `docker container ls`? Is the container running? I assume so because you mentioned being able to shell on it and netcat stats. I assume your test does *not* work from the host.

Comment: Aside: Docker provides some confusion. When you build (!) container images, you may include `EXPOSE XXXX` in the Dockerfile but this is documentary only. When you run (!) containers, you must either specific `--publish=XXXX:YYYY` to expose `:YYYY` on the host's port `:XXXX` or you can do e.g. `--net=host` to put the container on the host's network (and then need not use publish).

Comment: It would also be interesting for you to add `docker logs ...` for the container.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I added a screenshot of the Docker container ls command. 
I found a way to do what I was trying to do, I'll write a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to get the specific IP address for each container, which can be found by running `docker inspect (name of network)`.  In this case, `bridge`.

Then I needed to specify the IP address of the container.  I replaced the suggested address with that IP address and it worked.

[image: container reachable from another on the bridge network]